# How many majority elements can there be in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

You are given a sequence $S$ of $n$ numbers. An element $x$ in $S$ is called a *majority
element* if it occurs more than $n$/2 times in $S$.
This question asks you to describe two algorithms that decide if the sequence $S$ contains
a majority element; if it does, the algorithm returns it; otherwise, the algorithm returns the
message "there is no majority element".

a) How many majority elements can there be?

I said that there can be $n$ elements and I am proving it by induction. When I attempt to make a hypothesis or do the inductive step I get stuck. I need help proving that there are n majority elements in a sequence $S$ of $n$ numbers

Base Case: $n$ = 1

Let $x$ be an element of $S$ and let $i$ be the number of occurrences

$x$ = 1 = $n$

$x$ > ($n$/2 = 1/2)

Inductive Hypothesis: k is number of times element x occurs

Inductive step: Show that (k + 1) > (n + 1)/2

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Let $n$=2  How many majority elements can there be? Then try $n=3$ and $n=4$

Comment: Shouldn't we prove for n + 1 elements? Isn't that how induction works?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting induction, I was suggesting working these by hand to see if you see a pattern. If you think there can be $n$ majority elements, it seems you are defining majority as having at least as many as any other.  That is not what the definition you gave says.

Comment: I think that is what the definition he gave says, though. If $S=(1,1,2)$ then $S$ has two majority elements, right?

Comment: @EricStucky:  That is correct.  And $(1,1,1)$ has three.